# Why JQuery post is not transferring the data?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, post

I have a navbar defined in a html file called slick.html. I am trying to pass the id of a clicked navbar tab to the untitled.php. The untitled.php has other data in it. I am trying to isolate navbar to slick.html. I am trying to use JQuery post to transfer the data and using $_POST to access it, but I am not getting the value. I understand that it is something related to client side and server side using. The following is the code. I tried using ajax post but I didn't get any results.

slick.html(relevant parts)

```
<body>

          <ul class="nav nav-tabs ">
            <li class="active">
              <a id="soilProfile"   href="#tab_default_1" data-toggle="tab">
              Soil Profile </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a id="productivityIndex"    href="#tab_default_2" data-toggle="tab">
              Productivity Index </a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a id="Wetlands"    href="#tab_default_3" data-toggle="tab">
                Wetlands </a>
            </li>
          </ul>

//More Code
</div>
<script>
$(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
    $('#soilProfile').click(function(event) {
        console.log("About to post");
        var data = {id : event.target.id};  
        console.log(data);
        var request = $.ajax({
                        url: "untitled.php",
                        method: "POST",
                        data: { id : data },
        });

        console.log("AFTER POST");
    });
    $('#productivityIndex').click( function(event) {

    var data = {id : event.target.id};  
    $.post( "untitled.php", data );

});
$('#wetlands').click( function(event) {
    var data = {id : event.target.id};  
    $.post( "untitled.php", data );
});

});

</script>
</body>
```

untitled.php

```
<?php   
$var = $_POST['id']; 
echo var_dump($var);
// this fetches your post action
echo "this is my variable: " . $var; // this outputs the variable
?>
<html>
    <body>
    <object width=100%  data="slick.html"></object>
      <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
    });
      </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I don't understand why it's not working. Please inform me why or suggest me a better solution to go about this problem.

Comment: Simplification `data: { id : event.target.id},` and forget about this code `var data = {
              id : event.target.id
        };  `

Comment: Thanks! but the variable is still null!

Comment: try to remove event in function(event). $(#id).click(function(){..your code..})

Comment: @DennySutedja - I did it, but it didn't help my case.

Answer (score 0):

Noticed the in the ajax request you are using "untitled.php", but the page is titled "Untitled.php".  Case makes a difference on Linux.

Comment: fixed, but I don't think this is the solution for my problem. I appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the slick.html isn't just refreshed by the click on the anchor before the javascript is executed? Don't you need to prevent the default event?

Comment: Yes! I added event.preventDefault() under jQuery.click(), but it does not do any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you say u want to pass the id that clicked.

try this and se the console.log

```
$('#soilProfile').click(function() {
        console.log("About to post");
        var data = $(this).attr("id");         
        console.log(data);
        $.ajax({
               url: "untitled.php",
               type: "POST",
               data: { id : data }
        });

        console.log("AFTER POST");
    });
```

Comment: Yes! I tried it, but the problem is that the $_POST in untitled.php is still null. Thanks!

Comment: ah.. my bad. its should not method. it should Type

Comment: what do you mean by Type?

Comment: I tried your code now, but it is not the solution to my problem. I can access the id, but I can't  pass it to untitled.php. I think there is something wrong with my php $_POST and adding slick.html to untitled.php via <object> tag. I am not sure though!